# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutCubic'

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing, kwicks

There are slightly less than a billion similar questions on SO, with about the same number of reasons for the error. I just don't seem to find mine.

Kwicks accordian and the jQuery Easing plugin have been working for some time on my site and I'm unaware of any change that I have made that would cause them to misbehave:

http://donmorris.com

My console is showing two errors as I move my mouse over the accordian:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutCubic'
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

These seem to point to jquery.easing.js not being loaded, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Could someone here with sharper eyes please point out my mistake?

Comment: TO start with, you have jQuery linked 3 times and at least 2 are different versions.

Comment: Barbara, I see jQuery linked once on line 31. Can you point me to the others?

Comment: look at your page in developer tools or just view page source.  It must be from one of your drupal modules, because you have an additional 2 instances from ajax.googlapis.com.  And, maybe it's not the problem, but it jumped out at me.

Comment: Thanks, Barbara, I found it! One module and an external script were/are loading in additional copies of jQuery. I've not had any luck using jQuery's no-conflict mode, but at least I know where the problem is. Please **answer** the question so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to help, I copied the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  jQuery linked 3 times and at least 2 are different versions. Look at your page in developer tools or just view page source. It must be from one of your drupal modules, because you have an additional 2 instances from ajax.googlapis.com.